# Android App long Shortcut label Character start ellipsis after 15 or 16 characters?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As per [the Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/best-practices) related to App shortcut:

> Space is limited within the menu that shows your app's shortcuts in the launcher. When possible, limit the length of the "short description" of a shortcut to 10 characters, and limit the length of the "long description" to 25 characters.

So If I set long Label text as **Wi-Fi Signal Strength** in Google Pixel 5a device, App shortcut label start ellipses after 15 characters, Is that expected behavior? If so, then why does documentation says limit of "long description" to 25 characters.???

Or

Is there any way to display complete long label ie. **Wi-Fi Signal Strength** without any ellipses??

for eg:-

```
    ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, value)
                            .setShortLabel(shortLabel)
//limit of longLabel is 20 characters which is lesser than 25 then also it start ellipses after 15 characters.
                            .setLongLabel(longLabel) 
                            .setIcon(shortIcon)
                            .setIntent(intentShortcut)
                            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that expected behavior?

It will vary by home screen implementation and user settings (e.g., font scale), among possibly other criteria.

> If so, then why does documentation says limit of "long description" to 25 characters.???

It is merely a guideline.